# cmprsk python package example notebook doesn't work

Tags: python, r, statistics

I'm using `Python 3.11.1`. I've installed https://github.com/OmriTreidel/cmprsk (`1.0.0`, the latest version) on a new virtual environment, I've installed `rpy2 3.4.5` like the documentation suggested, I'm using `R 4.2.2` and I've installed the `cmprsk` package as suggested.

When I run the example notebook provided in the GitHub, I have `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (6,) + inhomogeneous part.`

- Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics
- Windows 11 Home
- I'm not using WSL

Comment: Can you share your operating system details {Unix, MacOSX, Windows}, and underlying hardware (intel, arm)? That in this case is important.

Comment: I've added it in my post, I hope this is enough?

Comment: Great - one last question are you running via WSL or directly on Windows?

Comment: I don't really know what WSL is, so I guess directly on Windows?

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux(WSL) is a feature of Windows that allows developers to run a Linux environment without the need for a separate virtual machine or dual booting. Anyway, now that is cleared up, I  will take a look and report back.

Comment: Not sure how it works in R, but from python perspective, the error is caused by this line: `dict(zip(r_list.names, map(np.array, r_list)))` in this line - https://github.com/OmriTreidel/cmprsk/blob/fbb3031cb0b0899273eedfc2cace57fee2a0d1db/cmprsk/rpy_utils.py#L71

if you change this line to `dict(zip(r_list.names[:9], map(np.array, r_list)))` it will work.

Comment: @rhn89 why only taking the first 9 elements of `r_list.names`?

Comment: @rhn89 (the fix does work by the way)

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows R counts from 1, Python counts from Zero. 1-based indexing in R makes it easier to work with data and perform calculations that are common in statistics and data analysis. I am not seeing the error you describe but off by one is a common problem when mixing R and Python.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows The git-repo was updated in the last few days. See https://github.com/OmriTreidel/cmprsk/issues?q= the edit relates to the line referenced https://github.com/OmriTreidel/cmprsk/pull/8/files

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction

So, I have set up a demo machine, and everything is working. Why? Well, it looks like the [cmprsk](https://github.com/OmriTreidel/cmprsk/) code base was kindly updated by [OmriTreidel](https://github.com/OmriTreidel) (A fine fellow), between when you found the problem and my testing below. The git-repo was updated in the last three days.

See [fix the VisibleDeprecationWarning #8](https://github.com/OmriTreidel/cmprsk/pull/8) the edit relates to the line referenced [fix the VisibleDeprecationWarning #8 files](https://github.com/OmriTreidel/cmprsk/pull/8/files) - so it appears the issue is resolved.

To that end, here are the setup details and the python [requirements.txt](https://gist.github.com/Technophobe01/953cceae93e92157f0cc451c4db4ee61) file that I used.

Feel free to try this and see if everything works, it works for me. Hoping this helps point you in the right direction.

### Config

```
    (venv) PS Z:\stackoverflow\75582335> systeminfo
    
    Host Name:                 STACKOVERFLOW
    OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
    OS Version:                10.0.22000 N/A Build 22000
    OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
    OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
    OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
    Registered Owner:          Windows User
    Registered Organization:
    ...
    Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
    System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
    Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
    System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
    Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
    Time Zone:                 (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
    Total Physical Memory:     16,095 MB
    Available Physical Memory: 7,429 MB
    Virtual Memory: Max Size:  19,039 MB
    Virtual Memory: Available: 6,647 MB
    Virtual Memory: In Use:    12,392 MB
    Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
    ...
    Network Card(s):           2 NIC(s) Installed.
                               [01]: Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
                                     Connection Name: Ethernet0
                                     DHCP Enabled:    Yes
```

---

### Setup:

Open a PowerShell terminal...
alt-shift - # Create a split window (top / bottom)
alt-shift + # create a split window (left right)

thus:

[image]

```
> mkdir Z:\stackoverflow\75582335
> cd Z:\stackoverflow\75582335
> winget install GitHub.cli
> winget install RProject.R
> winget install Rstudio
> winget install -e --id Python.Python.3.11 -v 3.11.1
> & 'C:\Program Files\R\R*\bin\x64\RScript.exe' -e "install.packages('cmprsk', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org', dependencies=TRUE)"
R
# Check it installed
> & 'C:\Program Files\R\R*\bin\x64\RScript.exe' -e "require('cmprsk');sessionInfo()"
> pip install virtualenv
> virtualenv venv2 --python=python3.11
> # Activate env2
> .\venv2\Scripts\activate.ps1
> gh repo clone OmriTreidel/cmprsk
> wget https://gist.github.com/Technophobe01/953cceae93e92157f0cc451c4db4ee61#file-requirements-txt 
> pip install -r requirements.txt
```

### ok, move to another window...

```
> cd Z:\stackoverflow\75582335
> .\venv2\Scripts\activate.ps1
> cd cmprsk
> jupyter-lab
```

### ok, now the browser should open...

[image]

### Run notebook...

Now we load 'package_usage.ipynb', and run it...

[image]